# Cryptic matlab error when computing eigs

Tags: matlab, runtime-error, eigenvector

I am trying to find the 2 eignevectors of the 2 smallest eigenvalues of a laplacian. I do this by

```
[v,c]=eigs(L,M,2,'SM');
```

Where `L` is the lapalcian and `M` is the mass matrix.

As a result I get the error

```
Error using eigs/checkInputs/LUfactorAminusSigmaB (line 1041)
The shifted operator is singular. The shift is an eigenvalue.
 Try to use some other shift please.


Error in eigs/checkInputs (line 855)
            [L,U,pp,qq,dgAsB] = LUfactorAminusSigmaB;

Error in eigs (line 94)
[A,Amatrix,isrealprob,issymA,n,B,classAB,k,eigs_sigma,whch, ...
```

Does this mean I am doing something wrong, or is this just matlab choosing a bad initial guess for its iteration process?

The matrices I am using should have a descent condition number...

Comment: Sure. Where should I upload them to? They are pretty large....

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem while implementing normalized cuts segmentation. The condition number is actually infinite because the smallest eigenvalue is 0, and this is basically what MATLAB's error message is about. It's running LU decomposition first.

I just added a multiple of I, 10*eps*speye, to the normalized Laplacian to improve conditioning and that fixed it.

Comment: Why did you choose specifically 10*eps*speye and not some other value?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with the eigs function. So I went the long (and maybe stupid) way but it did the job for me as my problem is not that big: (I will try to keep your notation)

% Solve the eigenvalue problem using the full matrices

```
[v,c]=eig(full(L),full(M));
```

% Sort out the eigenvalues using the sort function (the "-" sign is because you want the smallest real eigenvalues in magnitude)

```
[E,P] = sort(real(c),'descend'); % Here I am assuming you know all the eigenvalues have` negative real parts
```

% Now P is a vector that contains (in order) the indices of the row permutation operated by the % function sort.
% In order to obtain the two eigenvectors corresponding to the 2 smallest eigenvalues:

```
for k = 1:2
  index = P(k);
  lambda(k) = c(index,index); % use this to check if c(index,index)=E(k,k)
  eigvec(:,k) = v(:,index); % corresponding eigenvector
end
```

Hope this helps

G